# How to serve static files with Vite and access them at root path?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, webpack, vite

Question: I have recently switched my project from Webpack to Vite and need to serve static files at the root path. Specifically, I need to create static/styles/combined.css and static/js/bundle.js files. In my local development server, I have a route that depends on these files. Can someone suggest how to achieve this with Vite?

The technologies I'm using is ReactJS, Typescript, Ionic, Vite and yarn.

Comment: I have to run it on my local development server by just using "vite" command.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by adding dummy folders and files to my public folder. This allowed them to be included in both my local development server and the build folder.